# Total SUM of column cell giving wrong output in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I created a empty **List[ ]**  `List<GetTestFeeMap>reponseArray =[];` and adding data to this List[] everytime I'm calling my API function. When I go through my List item in `responseArray[]` and keep adding columns value, its just didn't give me the correct sum of my columns.

I believe its calculating like:

1st API call=> added 100 to list **||** ListItem `[100]` **||** Total sum= 100.

2nd API call=> added 1 to list **||** ListItem `[100,1]`|| Total sum = previous sum**100**+recent list item total **(100+1)**

My logic is   `feeSum += elem.fee! ;`

[image]

My Api function snippet

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    print(response.body);
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    print(jsonResponse);
    getTestFeeObj=GetTestFeeMap.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    setState(() {
      reponseArray.add(getTestFeeObj!); // Adding data to my Arraylist
      for(GetTestFeeMap elem in reponseArray){
              feeSum += elem.fee! ;
              discountSum += elem.discountedFee! ; // Doing calculation here
              bookingSum += elem.bookingFee! ;
            }
            print(feeSum);
            print(discountSum);
            print(bookingSum);
    });
```

Then printing  `List<GetTestFeeMap> reponseArray =[];`  List values in Datatable format and  Total sum of my column which I calculated in `setState(){}` in my API function. But its give me the wrong sum. Where did I go wrong?

```
 DataTable(
               columnSpacing: 13.0,
                columns: <DataColumn>[
                  //DataColumn(label: Text("encPartnerId")),
                  //DataColumn(label: Text("encTestId")),
                 // DataColumn(label: Text("TestName")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Fee")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Discounted Fee")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Booking Fee")),
                ],
                
                 rows:reponseArray.map((testRowData){
                  return DataRow(
                    cells: [
                      //DataCell(Text(testName)),
                      DataCell(Text (testRowData.fee!.toString() ?? '')),
                      DataCell(Text(testRowData.discountedFee !.toString() ?? '')),
                      DataCell(Text(testRowData.bookingFee!.toString() ?? ''))
                    ]
                  );
                }).toList()
            ),



            Container(
              child: 
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text("${feeSum}\n ${discountSum}  \n ${bookingSum}" ),
                  //  Text(discountSum ),
                  //   Text(bookingSum ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your feeSum variable still contains the value of the first call. Causing it to be 100 + 100 + 1. Make sure to reset the feeSum before doing the calculation again. You can do this by setting feeSum to 0 before the for loop.

Comment: Yes! by making `feeSum=0` before loop works! Thanks for your time